# Flutter : How to calculate value from textfields in listview.builder

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to retrieve and calculate input values from the textfield in listview .. how to achieve that?

Comment: Add some useful code snippets to better understand the problem

Comment: What have you tried? What problem did you run into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define a list of `TextEditingController` with the same length of your `listview`, then assign each `TextField` in your list an object of this array, which will enable you to retrieve the value whether when editing or when completed. This is an example of what I've said :

```
List<TextEditingController> textFieldControllers ;
```

in your list :

```
textFieldControllers[index] = new TextEditingController() ;
new TextField(controller: textFieldControllers[index]);
```

after that you can retrieve the value by :

```
textFieldControllers[index].text
```

Comment: its worked.. but how if we don't know the length of the list and i want to get the value from the textfield in listview?

Comment: you won't,unless you've assigned a certain `TextEditingController` to that field, then you'll be able to get its content.

Answer (score 1):

Brilliant. Added some stuff below to suit my use case.

First define a `List` like so `List<TextEditingController> textFieldControllers=[];`

then iterate through the the list used in creating the widgets in the `List.builder` like so.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < typesItem.length; i++) {
  textFieldControllers.add(TextEditingController());
}
```

where `typesItem` is the List item used in creating the Listbuilder widgets so as to maintain same lenght with your widgets dynamically.You can run this code on your `initState` method
there after goto your List.builder widget and initialise your controller like so.

```
 textFieldControllers[index] =  TextEditingController() ;
```

and set your TextField controllers in your return method like so

```
textFieldControllers[index]
```

You can therefore get all your value by using

```
  textFieldControllers[index].text;
```

You can manipulate to suit use your case as you want

Answer (score 0):

```
List<TextEditingController> machPresent=[];
machPresent.add(TextEditingController(text: ''));

Container(
          height: mainScreenHeight * 0.06,
          width: mainScreenWidth * 0.3,
          child: TextFormField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            controller: machPresent[index],
            enabled: true,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

**Press an action from a button**

```
Container(
  height: mainScreenHeight * 0.06,
  width: mainScreenWidth * 0.3,
  child: RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () {
      submitForm(index);},
   child: Text('Submit',textAlign: TextAlign.center),
 ),
),

  dynamic submitForm(int index) {
    var machValue=machPresent[index].text;
    var f= machValue;
    print(f);
  }
```

**Result**

```
I/flutter ( 7914): fff888- -- -- -Select Status
I/flutter ( 7914): sourav- -- -- -Select Status
```

[image]